# HDF5 Download Speeds From Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-s3, hdf5, h5py

I am looking to extract data from a massive collection, which totals 1.4 TB in size stored in HDF5 format. These data are sourced from NREL can be found publicly [here](https://data.openei.org/s3_viewer?bucket=nrel-pds-nsrdb&prefix=v3%2F) on an Amazon S3 bucket.

**The Workflow:**

I currently establish a link to this file using h5py and fsspec, isolate a dataset/subset `'clearsky_ghi'`, use a domain to isolate relevant points within the metadata, then further isolate which indices to extract based on specific range of time. The relevant code is as follows:

**The Code:**

```
import os, sys, re, ast, time, fsspec, h5py, s3fs
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

awsurl = 'https://nrel-pds-nsrdb.s3.amazonaws.com/v3/nsrdb_2019.h5'
bounds = [-130.1229448, 20.1788443, -60.8598418, 52.8170218]
with h5py.File(fsspec.open(awsurl, "rb").open(), "r") as awsfile:
        dataset = awsfile[datatype]
        meta = pd.DataFrame(awsfile['meta'][...])
        times = pd.to_datetime(awsfile['time_index'][...].astype(str))
        duologic = np.logical_and.reduce((times.month == 12, times.day== 1, times.minute == 0))
        timeindex = list(np.where(duologic)[0])
        coords = awsfile['coordinates'][...]
        continent = meta[(meta['longitude'] >= bounds[0]) & (meta['longitude'] <= bounds[2]) & (meta['latitude'] >= bounds[1]) & (meta['latitude'] <= bounds[3])]
        data = dataset[timeindex][continent.index]
```

**The General Issue:**

This code as shown above runs successfully, and I'm able to pass 24 indices from the `timeindex` output into the h5py File Object. However, my main concern is speed. Using NetHogs version 0.8.5-2build2 (running on Ubuntu 20.04), I've closely monitored the download speed from Amazon via the corresponding Python process where this script is running.

With a 100 MB/s connection (down & up) with no other downloads in the queue, I currently observe average download speeds of *1500-1600 KB/sec*, or 1/67th of my current bandwidth. Given this and how vast Amazon's cloud services are, I'm currently doubtful this is an issue with throttling on their end.

What alterations or additional strategies can I implement to increase my downloads of portions of this HDF5 file?

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

1. Are you accessing data within AWS or outside?

   1.1  If yes, are you running your Python code on the same region (e.g., us-west-2)?

   ```
    1.1.1 If yes, try your own S3 bucket. 
    1.1.2 If no, try same region.
   ```

   1.2 If no, try testing within AWS.
2. Try alternative RANGE-GET solutions.

   2.1 https://docs.opendap.org/index.php?title=DMR%2B%2B

   2.2 https://github.com/HDFGroup/hsds
3. If you have enough cloud budget, use EFS and DataSync.

   In Cloudnomics, performance = $.

   Check out my tutorial video about Cloud, Earthdata, and HDF: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB1I4rIPUyA&t=2s